# Android not getting proper street address from VCARD using ez-vcard

Tags: java, android, vcf-vcard

I'm using ez-vcard  (https://github.com/mangstadt/ez-vcard) for parsing VCARD string. For example one of VCARD string is

```
"BEGIN:VCARD\n" +
"N:Mandal;Saroj\n" +
"FN:Saroj Mandal\n" +
"ORG:xyz\n" +
"TITLE:Advisory Software Engineer\n" +
"TEL;WORK:022-123456\n" +
"TEL;CELL:1234567890\n" +
"TEL;FAX:1234567890\n" +
"ADR;ADDRESS:;;D-100, Tech Heights, Sainikwadi, Wadgaonshri;Pune;Maharashtra;411014;India\n" +
"LABEL;ADDRESS;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:D-100,Tech Heights, Sainikwadi, Wadgaonshri=0D=0Pune, Maharashtra=0D=0411014=0D=0India\n" +
"EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:hificoders@gmail.com\n" +
"URL;WORK:http://www.example.com\n" +
"END:VCARD";
```

In android I want street address from above example VCARD string
I have used below code

```
for(Address address :vcard.getAddresses()){
   Log.d(TAG, "Street address" + address.getStreetAddress());
}
```

But i'm getting only D-100 as street address , it should be D-100, Tech Heights, Sainikwadi, Wadgaonshri, but If I remove comma(,) from above VCARD then Im getting whole string. Please give some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma characters must be escaped in the ADR property.  Put backslashes before all the commas.

```
"ADR;ADDRESS:;;D-100\, Tech Heights\, Sainikwadi\, Wadgaonshri;Pune;Maharashtra;411014;India\n" +
```

Also, why the heck to do you have a value-less "ADDRESS" parameter in your property??  Remove that, please.

```
"ADR:;;D-100\, Tech Heights\, Sainikwadi\, Wadgaonshri;Pune;Maharashtra;411014;India\n" +
```

**EDIT (Jul 27 2015):**

To answer the question in your comment:

To force the parser to treat commas as normal characters, you can register a custom scribe class which extends the standard `AddressScribe` scribe and overrides its parsing function:

```
VCardReader reader = new VCardReader(...);
reader.getScribeIndex().register(new AddressScribe() {
    @Override
    protected Address _parseText(String value, VCardDataType dataType, VCardVersion version, VCardParameters parameters, List<String> warnings) {
        String components[] = value.split(";");
        int i = 0;

        Address property = new Address();
        property.setPoBox(next(components, i++));
        property.setExtendedAddress(next(components, i++));
        property.setStreetAddress(next(components, i++));
        property.setLocality(next(components, i++));
        property.setRegion(next(components, i++));
        property.setPostalCode(next(components, i++));
        property.setCountry(next(components, i++));
        return property;
    }

    private String next(String components[], int index) {
        if (index >= components.length) {
            return null;
        }
        String next = components[index];
        return (next.length() > 0) ? next : null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there any method to get ADR property directly?

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks very much